# Why does Henley always wear gloves?

Tags: now-you-see-me

In the movie [Now You See Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/), Henley wears gloves *all* the time. Did I miss some explanation for this in the movie? Or is there some out of movie explanation, like she's a germophobe?

[image]

Comment: She doesn't wear gloves while robbing the armored truck in Paris and doesn't wear gloves in her piranha stunt. who knows, just likes to leave no trace...except while robbing a armored car.

Comment: I noticed that the gloves are black but red on the palms so I always figured it was supposed to be ironic - 'caught red handed'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The in-universe explanation is that she's germophobic. From [an interview](http://www.glamourmagazine.co.uk/celebrity/entertainment/monitor/2013/06/jesse-eisenberg-isla-fisher-now-you-see-me-interview):

> **Does Henley wear gloves so often for any particular reason?**
>
> *Jesse*: Germs.
>
> *Isla*: She's germ-phobic.

That said, she is *not* wearing gloves during the piranha stunt.

Comment: Why would that be an out-of-movie explanation when they're obviously talking about *Henley* and not *Isla*. (Yet I'm not sure that wasn't just a joke they made, anyway, but since we don't know it makes for a valid in-move explanation)

Comment: like Christian said, they're talking about Henley. And, the reason she's not wearing gloves during the piranha stunt is because that really wouldn't have made any difference in protecting her from all the "horrible germs" in the tank.. though, one might wonder why she'd do a trick like that in the first place considering her germophobia...

Comment: @ChristianRau It's an out-of-movie explanation because it isn't explained _in_ the movie.

Comment: @coleopterist Well Ok, from that viewpoint you might be right, still the more important distinction would be if the reason itself is in-movie or out-of-movie (apart from its mere explanation). Yet you got a point.

Comment: @ChristianRau There's a sequel planned. We might have to wait until that comes out :)

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that at times, she has a "magic double" performing the tight hand shots. There may be enough differences in the hands to notice the difference so they cover it up using gloves.

Answer (score 0):

She wasn't wearing gloves before the piranha stunt and from then onward she is always wearing gloves. The only other time you don't see her wearing gloves is when they are robbing the truck in Paris. She might be wearing the gloves to stop her fingerprints from getting all over everything but that is weird because the boys (J. Daniel Atlas, Jack Wilder and Merritt McKinney) never bothered with that idea. She also looks really good wearing gloves! Maybe she knew that and she liked the idea so she decided to continue wearing them. Who knows? But she sure as hell looks really really good in them!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There was an on-set accident in which she got burned a little, and it happened after shooting the Paris and piranha scenes.